# For loop json Google Script

Tags: json, loops, google-apps-script

I can't for the life of me figure out how to loop over the following json snippet to retrieve the resource_id value to produce the following list {1, 2, 3}.

```js
var dataStringify = 
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have gotten as far as logging the following to determine that iterating on *items* with the following dot notation would yield approximately what I need, but I can't seem to be able write a working loop.

```
Logger.log(dataStringify.items[0].events[0].parameters[1].value);
```

`this yields just the first value "1" rather than a list {1,2,3}`

Comment: I think u need to do parameters[0] instead of [1], dataStringify.items[0].events[0].parameters[0].value

Comment: Oh that was a mistake. I tried to simplify the JSON. In the original the 1 was needed to access the right parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state you want "a list" `{1,2,3}` - but that `{ ... }` is an object and as such it has to contain `key: value` pairs. So your example output is not valid.

If you want an array `[ 1, 2, 3]` instead, then one approach is to drill down into the nested arrays as follows:

```js
var dataStringify = 
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "resource_id",
                            "value": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var resultsArray = [];

dataStringify.items.forEach((item) => {
  item.events.forEach((event) => {
    event.parameters.forEach((parameter) => {
      resultsArray.push( parameter.value );
    } );
  } );
} );

console.log( resultsArray );
```

The result is an array of strings, since that is how the source data is arranged:

```
[ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

If you want `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` then you can [convert the strings to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript) as you push them to the results array.

Comment: This is a great answer. Very thorough and well explained, but when I fit it back into my original json with a bunch of other 'items', 'events', and 'parameters' it didn't work correctly and just printed off all values for all parameters. Overall I feel like your answer is better but it didn't apply back to my original script as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a combination of the two answers above. The script below works remarkably well. Thanks everyone!

````
var resultsArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
resultsArray.push(dataStringify.items[i].events[0].parameters[1].value)
}

console.log(resultsArray);```
````

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
  Logger.log(dataStringify.items[i].events[0].parameters[0].value);
}
```

`items` is the variable you want to loop around, right?